# SSRS column filters

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

According to user requirement, We need to have the filter functionality on each column of the SSRS report after it is rendered. The required functionality is similar to which is provided by kendo grid or jQuery DataTable (see screenshot).

[image: kendo grid column filter]

[image: jQuery Data Table column filter]

As per my analysis till now, I found no solution to have such functionality on SSRS report.
I just wanted to know if its possible to have such a functionality on SSRS report or not.

Comment: What you want is not available in SSRS out of the box.

Comment: The requirements are for an interactive app, not a ssrs report

Comment: thanks guys, I just wanted to confirm that this functionality is not available in SSRS.

Answer (score 1):

You can setup this kind of sorting in SSRS.  It is called "Interactive Sorting".

MSDN has [details on how to set this up](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd283102.aspx).

Basically you have to right click the `TextBox` that you want to be able to sort (not the actual column header), choose `Text Box Properties`, and then click on the `Interactive Sorting` tab, and choose to enable it.

[image]

Comment: sorry @jesse , my question is for having interactive filter functionality

Comment: Oops!  I don't know why I was thinking sorting instead of filter.  Sorry for the off topic answer.

Answer (score 0):

There might be a way to sort of fake this in SSRS, however I am not sure this will be a workable solution.  You would need to create a new parameter for all the columns you want to filter on.  Depending on your input, multiple values or singular values, check the correct checkbox in the General screen, and create a dataset of each column.
Select Distinct [Column] From [Table].  Then you can add these values in 'Available Values', Get values from a query, and specify the dataset.  Finally you need to filter the main dataset on the parameter.  Column equals Parameter, or Column IN Parameter for multi-select.  You may run into some NULLs, but these are easily handled, just use an IsNothing() expression to exclude them.  This will then require selecting a parameter value at report execution, but you can specify and default value to return everything.  This obviously causes a postback to apply changes to the filter, so again, it may not be a workable solution